# Пересылка группы медиафайлов Aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Реализован простой бот для пересылки сообщения от пользователя на конкретный user_id. Но при отправке группы из фотографий\видео они пересылаются по отдельности. Тоесть сначала пересылается первое фото с описанием, потом остальные два без описания.

```
import logging
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


# Инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher()

# Обработчик всех сообщений от пользователей
@dp.message()
async def forward_to_admin(message: types.Message):
    # Здесь нужно указать user_id администратора

    admin_user_id = 11111

    try:
        # Пересылаем все фотографии из группы как одно сообщение
        await bot.forward_media_group(chat_id=admin_user_id, from_chat_id=message.chat.id,
                                      message_id=message.message_id)
        await message.answer("Группа фотографий успешно переслана администратору!")
        
    try:
        # Пересылаем сообщение администратору
        await bot.forward_message(chat_id=admin_user_id, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
        await message.answer("Сообщение успешно переслано администратору!")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Ошибка при пересылке сообщения: {e}")
        await message.answer("Произошла ошибка при пересылке сообщения. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```